# Is declaring a Node.js redis client as a const in multiple helpers a safe way to use it?

Tags: node.js, redis, ioredis

This is a little hard articulate so I hope my title isn't too terrible.

I have a frontend/backend React/Node.js(REST API) Web app that I want to add Redis support to for storing retrieving app global settings and per-user specific settings (like language preference, last login, etc... simple stuff) So I was considering adding a /settings branch to my backend REST API to push/pull this information from a redis instance.

This is where my Node.js inexperience comes through. I'm looking at using the ioredis client and it seems too easy. If I have a couple of helpers (more than one .js which will call upon redis) will constructing the client as a `const` in each be safe to do? Or is there another recommended approach to reusing a single instance of it be the way to go?

Here's a sample of what I'm thinking of doing. Imagine if I had 3 helper modules that require access to the redis client. Should I declare them as `const` in each? Or centralize them in a single helper module, and get the client from it? Is there a dis-advantage to doing either?

```
const config = require('config.json');
const redis_url = config.redis_url;

//redis setup
const Redis = require('ioredis');
const redis = new Redis(redis_url);

module.exports = {
   test
}

async function test(id) {
   redis.get(id, function (err, result) {
   if (err) {
      console.error(err);
      throw(err);
   } else {
      return result;
   }
});
```

Thank you.

Answer (score 2):

**If no redis conflicts...**

If the different "helper" modules you are referring to have no conflicts when interacting with redis, such as overwriting / using the same redis keys, then I can't see any reason not to use the same redis instance (as outlined by garlicman) and export this to the different modules in which it is used.

**Otherwise use separate redis databases...**

If you do require separate redis database connections, redis ships with 16 databases so you can specify which to connect to when creating a new instance - see below:

```
const redis = new Redis({ // SET UP CONFIG FOR CONNECTION TO REDIS
    port: 6379, // Redis port
    host: 127.0.0.1, // Redis host
    family: 4, // 4 (IPv4) or 6 (IPv6)
    db: 10, // Redis database to connect to
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Normally what I would do (in Java say) is implement any explicit class with singleton access the hold the connection and any connection error/reconnect handling.

All modules in Node.js are already singletons I believe, but what I will probably go with will be a client class to hold it and my own access related methods. Something like:

```
const config = require('config.json');
const Redis = require("ioredis");

class Redis {

    constructor(){
        client = new Redis(config.redis_url);
    }

    get(key) {
        return this.client.get(key);
    }

    set(key, value, ttl) {
        let rp;
        if (ttl === 0) {
            rp = this.client.set(key, value);
        }
        else {
            rp = this.client.set(key, value)
            .then(function(res) {
                this.client.expire(key, ttl);
            });
        }
        return rp;
    }

}

module.exports = new Redis;
```

I'll probably include a data_init() method to check and preload an initial key/value structure on first connect.